# I get error 3125 when I try to delete a linked table

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to delete all the linked tables in my front end, but it fails on the first table with the error: 3125 "'attendeesSearch' is not a valid name. Make sure that it does not include invalid characters or punctuation and that it is not too long.".

This table contains a multi-valued field. I include this because it may be an issue.

I've tried using "Drop table..." SQL and DoCmd.DeleteObject method.

My routine:

```
Sub relinkRequestHelp()
   Const csConnnectPrefix  As String = ";DATABASE="
   Dim bLenConnectPrefix   As Byte
   Dim db As dao.Database
   Dim tbl As dao.TableDef
   Dim s As String

   On Error GoTo eh
   bLenConnectPrefix = Len(csConnnectPrefix)
   Set db = CurrentDb()
   For Each tbl In db.TableDefs
      If Left(tbl.Connect, bLenConnectPrefix) = csConnnectPrefix Then
'         s = "DROP TABLE " & tbl.Name & ";"
'         Debug.Print s
'         db.Execute s, dbFailOnError
'         Debug.Print , db.RecordsAffected
         DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, tbl.Name
      End If
   Next

   Exit Sub

eh: Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description
End Sub
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this [post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/3125-is-not-a-valid-name-make-sure/e860329d-12e2-4a25-b9ce-680bfa945faf?page=1), Daniel Pineault suggested I remove the troubled table from all relationships.

Once I did that, I was able to delete the linked table.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the current object from the collection. That works for me:

```
For Each tbl In db.TableDefs
    If Left(tbl.Connect, bLenConnectPrefix) = csConnnectPrefix Then
        db.TableDefs.Delete tbl.Name
    End If
Next
```

Comment: @ErikA: You are right. Thanks! I've edited the answer.

Comment: I get the same error using the TableDefs.Delete method.